# Associator of a 2-cocycle is a 3-cocycle

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, nonassociative-algebras

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra with underlying vector space $V$ and let $F_1:V\times V\to V$ be a bilinear map. Let $A:V\times V\times V\to V$ be the associator of $F_1$, i.e.

$A(a,b,c)=F_1(F_1(a,b),c)-F_1(a,F_1(b,c))$.

$F_1$ can be thought as an element of the Hochschild complex, in particular, $F_1\in C^2(A,A)=\hom_k(A\otimes A,A)$. According to [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970484?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (Chapter I, section 2, page 64), the associator of $F_1$ is an element of $Z^3(A,A)$ whenever $F_1\in Z^2(A,A)$. This means that if $\delta F_1=0$, then $\delta A=0$, where

$\delta F_1 (a,b,c)=aF_1(b,c)-F_1(ab,c)+F_1(a,bc)-F_1(a,b)c$

and

$\delta A(a,b,c,d)=aA(b,c,d)-A(ab,c,d)+A(a,bc,d)-A(a,b,cd)+A(a,b,c)d$.

But by definition

$\delta A(a,b,c,d)=a[F_1(F_1(b,c),d)-F_1(b,F_1(c,d))]-[F_1(F_1(ab,c),d)-F_1(ab,c),d)]+[F_1(F_1(a,bc),d)-F_1(a,F_1(bc,d))]-[F_1(F_1(a,b),cd)-F_1(a,F_1(b,cd))]+[F_1(F_1(a,b),c)-F_1(a,F_1(b,c))]d$

If $F_1$ was $A$-bilinear and not only $k$-bilinear, then I could simplify to get $\delta A(a,b,c,d)=F_1(\delta F_1(a,b,c),d)+A(a,b,c)d$. But I still have that term $A(a,c,d)d$ which doesn't depend on $\delta F_1$. And this is asuming more than I can. I have no idea what to do if $F_1$ is only $k$-bilinear.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "algebra morphism" and "$k$-linear"? $F_1$ is a map of two arguments.

Comment: If you want a safe but boring way to verify the claim, all you need is to rewrite the assumption $\delta F_1 = 0$ as $F_1\left(ab, c\right) = a F_1\left(b,c\right) - F_1\left(a, bc\right) + F_1\left(a, b\right) c$ for all $a, b, c$, and treat this as a way to get rid of products in the first argument of $F_1$. Keep applying this to the expansion of $\delta A\left(a, b, c, d\right)$ (both for inner and for outer arguments). You should end up with $0$ because everything should cancel out in the end.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I meant $k$-bilinear. I noticed that I didn't use "algebra morphism" properly. I meant that $F_1(ab,c)=aF_1(b,c)$ and the same on the left argument. But I only have that when $a\in k$. Thanks, I'll try to follow your advice